# EMMA : Stackmap Table Error : Bad Offset Exception

Tags: testing, netbeans, runtime-error, emma

I using EMMA plugin.
At first I 've run test normally,but there is a problem when I activate coverage collection and run test again it become failed as show in the picture

I 've try to add -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in JVM argument but It's not work.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault.
I 've try to add -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in the VM options instead of argument and it's work now thank you.